# Merge Sort C implementation with linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, mergesort

I'm having a segmentation fault core dumped when trying to merge sort with linked lists in C. Can't seem to track the root cause of the issue:

this is my node structure:

```
typedef struct node0* node;
struct node0{
    int val;
    node next;
}node0;
```

this is my splitting function:

```
node* divide(node head){
    float mid = ceilf((float)length(head)/2);
    node* ret = malloc(sizeof(node)*2);
    node tmp1 = head;
    while (mid>1){
        tmp1 = tmp1->next;
        mid--;
    }
    node tmp2 = tmp1->next;
    tmp1->next = NULL;
    ret[0] = head;
    ret[1]=tmp2;
    return ret;
}
```

this is my merging function:

```
node mergesorted(node head1, node head2){
    node ret = NULL;
    if(head1 == NULL) return head2;
    else if(head2 == NULL) return head1;
    if(head1->val <= head2->val){
        ret = head1;
        ret->next = mergesorted(head1->next, head2);
    } else {
        ret = head2;
        ret->next = mergesorted(head1, head2->next);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and this is the regular merge sort algorithm:

```
node merged(node head){
    if(length(head)>1){
        node *lists = divide(head);
        merged(lists[0]);
        merged(lists[1]);
        return mergesorted(lists[0], lists[1]);

    }
}
```

main:

```
int main() {
    node l1 = create_node(1);
    l1->next = create_node(3);
    l1->next->next = create_node(4);
    l1->next->next->next= create_node(2);
    l1 = merged(l1);
    print_list(l1);
}
```

after adding some prints I get the following log:

```
deviding: 1-->3-->4-->2-->
devided into:
l1: 1-->3-->
l2: 4-->2-->

deviding: 1-->3-->
devided into:
l1: 1-->
l2: 3-->

merging: 1-->
with: 3-->
merged:1-->3-->

deviding: 4-->2-->
devided into:
l1: 4-->
l2: 2-->

merging: 4-->
with: 2-->
merged:2-->4-->

merging: 1-->3-->
with: 4-->
merged:1-->3-->4-->

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

As it appears at the final merge the right hand list pointer seems to be null!

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because of following fragments:

```
    if(head1->val <= head2->val){
        ret = head1;
        ret->next = mergesorted(head1->next, head2);
    } else {
        ret = head2;
        ret->next = mergesorted(head1, head2->next);
    }
```

If you see, you are assigning a new "head" every time the value is lesser or greater! That shouldn't be clearly the intension.

Rather you need to create / appened a new head only when the resultant node is `empty` or `NULL`.

```
    if(head1->val <= head2->val){
        if(ret == NULL){
          ret = head1;
        }
        ret->next = mergesorted(head1->next, head2);
    } else {
        if(ret == NULL){
          ret = head2;
        }
        ret->next = mergesorted(head1, head2->next);
    }
```

I didn't see any other problem in your code.